# Do transferring energy and applying force to a body imply same?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, work

Do transferring energy and applying force to a body imply same meaning? When we say, "I throw a ball using my pushing force so on the other hand, can I say that I transferred my kinetic energy to the ball therefore it became moving.

Comment: Momentum is being conserved when you throw the ball, but kinetic energy is not. Your body converted chemical potential energy to kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

No. In a uniform circular orbit the orbiting body maintains constant energy while a constant force, only changing in direction, operates on that body.

Kinetic energy changes when a net force is applied *in the direction that an object is moving*. It will reduce if the net force opposes velocity, or increase if net force supports velocity.

Comment: Sorry. I don't find your answer easy to understand..

Comment: Let me explain the structure of the answer. There is the *answer itself*, which is one word long. ("No."). Then there is an explanation of a *counterexample* (circular motion) where there *is* a force, but there is *no energy transfer*. For this reason, they **don't** have the same meaning. Then there is an extra paragraph which highlights (in *italics*) the crucial concept which you are missing: that a force, to transfer energy, needs to act *in the direction that the object is moving*. That direction is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you apply a net force to a mass (please note the word "net"), the object become accelerated . This acceleration means the body changes velocity, and a change in velocity means there is a change in the energy, because of the energy formula:

> $E=\frac{1}{2}mV^2$

The case of the circle is particularly interesting, because there is a force applied but the energy does not change. This is the result of applying force to decrease the velocity of the mass in a direction (say the x axis, if the mass initially moves over the x axis) while at the same time you apply force to accelerate the same mass in a perpendicular direction (the y axis). This makes the velocity-energy to keep constant while you apply a centripetal force. You can check this by yourself by decomposing the centripetal force in its x-y components and calculating work done (and work done = energy). Or, you can check the [demonstration](http://stalinbeltran.com/2015/02/08/does-the-centripetal-force-do-some-work/).